# Can someone explain me how this code works? (Palindrome C++)

Tags: c++, palindrome

I have a working code but I don't quite understand how it works, I know it's meaning and use but I don't understand how it works.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
   int n, num, digit, rev = 0;
     cout << "Enter a positive number: ";
     cin >> num;
     n = num;
     do
     {
         digit = num%10;
         rev = (rev*10) + digit;
         num = num/10;
     }while (num!=0);
     cout << " The reverse of the number is: " << rev << endl;
     if (n==rev)
       cout << " The number is a palindrome";
     else
       cout << " The number is not a palindrome";

    return 0;  
}
```

I don't understand this part:

```
     do
     {
         digit = num%10;
         rev = (rev*10) + digit;
         num = num/10;
     }while (num!=0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reverses `num` by iterating over the digits of `num`. For each digit it adds it to the right of `rev`.

```
digit = num%10; // Find the 1s digit of num
rev = (rev*10) + digit; // Push digit to the right of rev
num = num/10; // Remove the 1s digit of num
```

An example walkthrough for `num = 123`:

```
d = 0, r = 0, n = 123.

d = 3   // 123%10
r = 3   // 0*10 + 3
n = 12  // 123/10

d = 2   // 12%10
r = 32  // 3*10+2
n = 1   // 12/10

d = 1   // 1%10
r = 321 // 32*10+1
n = 0   // 1/10
```

And `321` is indeed the reverse of `123`.

Answer (score 0):

Let´s reorder it a bit and forget the loop for now.

```
digit = num%10;
num = num/10;
rev = (rev*10) + digit;
```

If you enter 1234, `num` is 1234 before the loop, and `rev` is 0.

First line gets you 4 of 1234 (modulo, the remainder of a division).

The you divide num by 10, which normally would be 123.4, but it´s an `int`, so only 123. These two lines essentially remove the last digit of num (and store it in digit).

The, the last line simply "concatenates" the digit to rev.
If `rev` is 123 and `digit` is 4, you´ll get `123*10+4=1234`

So, remembering the loop: Digits are taken from the end of `num` and put at the end of `rev` instead. Until there is no `num` anymore.